# MS Graph API returns 401

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am setting up an Azure function to send out emails using MS Graph API in python.

I have registered the app and have been granted the Mail.Send application permission.
My function for sending emails through the API is pretty much copied from
https://kontext.tech/article/795/python-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-api:

```
import json
import msal
import requests

client_id = '123'
client_secret = '123'
tenant_id = '123'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

# Function for sending an email using MS Graph API
def ms_graph_send_mail():
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_credential=client_secret,
        authority=authority)

    scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

    result = None
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

    if not result:
        print(
            "No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.")
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

    if "access_token" in result:
        print("Access token is " + result["access_token"])
        userId = 'sender@company.co'
        endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
        toUserEmail = "receiver@company.co"
        email_msg = {
            'Message':
                {
                    'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                    'Body':
                        {
                            'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."
                        },
                    'ToRecipients':
                        [
                            {
                                'EmailAddress': {
                                    'Address': toUserEmail
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                },
            'SaveToSentItems': 'true'
            }
        r = requests.post(url=endpoint,
                          headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result["access_token"]},
                          json=email_msg)

        print(r)
        if r.ok:
            print('Sent email successfully')
        else:
            print(r.json())
    else:
        print(result.get("error"))
        print(result.get("error_description"))
        print(result.get("correlation_id"))


ms_graph_send_mail()
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following output:

```
No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory. 
Access token is eyJ0eXAiO..... 
<Response [401]>
{'error': {'code': 'UnknownError', 'message': '', 'innerError': {'date': '2022-05-18T13:36:22', 'request-id': 'b9a...', 'client-request-id': 'b9a...'}}}
```

Googling a bit reveals that 401 is a problem with authentication, but as mentioned the necessary permission is granted, so I don't know what I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please put the token in https://jwt.ms and see if the permission is present or not.

Comment: It seems fine to me:
{
(...)
"appidacr": "1",
(...)
"roles": [
    "Mail.Send"
  ],
(...)
}